# Error While Extracting files - "Error setting owner"

Tags: xubuntu, 13.10, extract

I'm using Xubuntu 13.10. Downloaded Eclipse. Tried to extract the tar file and I got the error as seen in the image.

[image]

I have tried the following:

- Opened it up in the archive manager. It opens up properly.
- Tried to downloaded it multiple times just to make sure the downloaded file is not corrupted. It isn't.
- changing permissions so that everyone can read write the file.
- Tried to extract in different folders.

Please help me extract the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am getting the same error with the archive manager on 13.10.

You can extract it via the command line:

```
tar xzf eclipse.tar.gz
```

Comment: Everyone is downloading eclipse!! I wonder why they did not push the latest version to Ubuntu repos?!